# Can I use answer text in a tshirt?

Tags: support, legal, t-shirt

Since the epic [Stack Overflow 3rd Anniversary Tee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition) was never made available for purchase, I thought I'd make my own shirt.

Using a tshirt design site, I put "The <center> cannot hold; it is too late" from Bobince's [classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

The back has the Unicode-garbled "Tony the Pony He Comes," along with a link to the original answer in accordance with the CC-Wiki license.

Before I ordered it and made it real, I just wanted to make sure this was okay. Is it?

<sup>**N.B** - I'm not using the logo at all, as I'm aware that raises more legal issues. I'm just using the CC-Wiki licensed text.</sup>

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3630/how-can-we-use-the-stackoverflow-name-logo) covers logo usage and mentions text usage in passing, but it's still not super-clear, so I wanted to get some official weigh-in here. :)

Comment: By CC by SA, you must place a username and working link. Have fun convincing people to click the link on your tshirt!

Comment: @Manishearth so in other words it's technically illegal? What does "working" link mean?

Comment: it was a joke :) CC-by-SA/SO policy says you must credit the user on the tshirt, as well as providing a link. If the tshirt says `http://stackoverflow.com/answers/......` somewhere, I think its OK. Just thought that the image of people tapping links on a tshirt was funny :/

Comment: @Manishearth oh i know you were kidding. :) I'm just tired, so I didn't textually laugh (don't worry! I grinned in real life). According to  CC by SA 4.a, though, evidently I'm supposed to link to the license itself. I guess I could print that on the inside of the tee... :P

Comment: I need one of these shirts.

Comment: Let me put it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkmGu.png

Answer (score 11):

Go for it - just make sure you send me one!

Comment: I totally agree, and I'm sure bobince won't mind in this specific case, but this answer still is factually incorrect: when reproducing CC content, technically, you have to attribute the *author* as well - even on a T-Shirt, *and not even Stack Exchange, Inc. can waive that requirement.* It clearly doesn't matter in this case, but it might next time someone has this question (say because they want to sell a T-Shirt with SO content on it). More reading: [Attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Comment: @Pekka according to that blog post, technically I'd have to have 2 links on the shirt, then, right? the original question and Bobince's user profile? I'm going to go ahead with it since everyone agrees, but  I will put the link to the original question on the back.

Comment: @Geoff: What's your shirt size? :P

Comment: @Thomas technically, I think that's right: you'd have to link to the SO question and to bobince. You could, however, take a shortcut and ask bobince for permission, which would save you from having to link anything :)

Comment: @Pekka ah yes, that would be ideal :) I'll ask him. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The terms of the site - CC-by-SA - require you to attribute your source, and - if you were to make more of these T-shirts - only offer it under similar terms.

<s>I've never heard anything formal or official about clothing and CC-by-SA text, so I'm willing to bet that you couldn't take the text, make the T-shirt and profit from it.  A private shirt, though - I don't think anyone's going to come after you.</s>

**EDIT:**  Looking back on the [full legal text](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) of CC-by-SA 3.0 Unported, section 3(a) jumps out at me.

> `3`. License Grant. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, Licensor hereby grants You a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive,
>   perpetual (for the duration of the applicable copyright) license to
>   exercise the rights in the Work as stated below:
>
> a) to Reproduce the Work, to incorporate the Work into one or more
>   Collections, and to Reproduce the Work as incorporated in the
>   Collections;

A t-shirt would be considered a reproduction, the end result would be royalty-free (meaning,  as best as I can tell that you wouldn't owe StackExchange money), and the license would allow someone else to use the same work in the same manner (by CC-by-SA).

I think you can do it.  Place the CC-by-SA tag somewhere near the bottom/back, and/or place a QR code to the full license (finally a use for QR codes!) to satisfy 4(a).

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking. It'd be nice to hear from a company representative though.

Comment: @ThomasShields:  Yeah, I agree. I'd *really* like to see something [as funny as **the** post] make it onto a T-shirt.

Comment: I think [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rakh4.png) is the closest you'll get. It's not for sale, though, hence my creation of a lesser (yet hopefully still funny) one.

Comment: The store should sell Jon Skeet Facts t-shirts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9182/172108

Comment: Would that still hold if Bobince wanted to make his own t-shirt line from that answer?  Does he have ownership of it?  Would anyone be able to if they were the author?

Comment: @JeffMercado:  Yeah, that's the question.  I'm no lawyer, but I would figure that, if he wanted to make his own, there probably wouldn't be an issue.  I would presume that anyone would be able to, if it were their own comment.  The main catch is that *you probably couldn't sell it*.  I'd rather hear an official answer in terms of clothing creation.  I'll look around and see what I could find.

Comment: @JeffMercado that's the trick, isn't it? Technically his answer (even if he holds copyright) is licensed by StackExchange, and he agreed to that by accepting terms and conditions, so *technically* even he can't sell it unless he works a deal with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ThomasShields No, Bobince was the original creator, and the CC-BY-SA is a non-exclusive license, so Bobince is free to do with it whatever he wants, including profiting from it.

Comment: @waiwai933 oooh, okay. Didn'tk now about the "non-exclusive" part.

Comment: I think your edit nails it. I'll leave it open for the night to see if a company rep chimes in, otherwise I'll accept this.