# May I use an image derived from the Stack Overflow logo?

Tags: discussion, copyright

The owners of the C# room are working on starting a [wiki](http://csharp-room-wiki.azurewebsites.net) for the room. I thought it would be fitting to identify with Stack Overflow in the logo, but it seems I wouldn't be permitted to use the Stack Overflow logo in a derived logo for the wiki.

Would I be allowed to use a derived logo on the wiki? If so, under what conditions? If not, is this the kind of thing that I could get special permission for?

Here is an example of what I was thinking of:

[image]

Comment: That is so cute.

Comment: [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3630/how-can-we-use-the-stackoverflow-name-logo) (would be an exact dupe, but really it's a request for permission so that distinguishes it).

Comment: Its a PHP wiki.  **ಠ_ಠ** At least you could have taken a fork off of screwturn.  Or maybe even offered to [help supporting it](http://blog.screwturn.eu/2012/07/22/volunteers-recruiting/).

Comment: @Won't I'm hosting the wiki - never heard of screwturn.  I'll take a look into it.

Comment: and yes, I'm aware of the irony.

Comment: I'm tempted to file a DMCA notice about that logo you posted and see what happens ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa Not much, since a notice should only be filed by the copyright holder. ;)

Comment: That doesn't stop the big media companies :) But I understand it would be strange to see your logo in a DMCA request :D

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Things men make are never "Cute". They're manly, awesome, rugged, august, bodacious... but never cute... (Unless you're talking about my daughter, but she'd prefer the word Princess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The short answer is:

No, you cannot use a derived logo.

From our handy [Trademark Guidance page](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (which you can find in the "legal" link in the footer of every page on our network):

> Use of Our Name or Logo in Advertising
>
> - Do use the most current logo where applicable and permitted.
> - Do use the proper name for our company, product, or service (see "Proper use of the Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange Name" below).
> - **Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.**
> - Do not use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false  sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.
> - Do not use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused with our name or logo.
> - **Do not distort or alter our logo in any way**.
> - Do not use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.
> - Do not use any other artwork from our network without explicit permission.

### The good news is:

You may use the actual Stack Overflow logo (available at https://stackexchange.com/about/logos). You should include a disclaimer on the wiki site that says the SO logo and trademarks are used with permission from SE Inc. Please also follow the other trademark and copyright guidelines (e.g., make sure that the page doesn't look like it is own, maintained, or endorsed by Stack Exchange, make sure you properly attribute content taken from SO, etc.).

Comment: :( I was afraid of that. My most brilliant idea in years, all for naught. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @KendallFrey Sorry. I do like your logo, I think it's cute. The problem is that if we start letting people make derivatives for their own projects, it dilutes our original logo and brand.